# scoped variable not showing up in ng repeat which works fine without ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I was following basic ionic tutorial on its todo app:

```
<body ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

<!-- Center content -->
<ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">Todo</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <!-- our list and list items -->
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        {{task.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu-content>
</body>
```

And at app.js

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tasks = [
    { title: 'Collect coins' },
    { title: 'Eat mushrooms' },
    { title: 'Get high enough to grab the flag' },
    { title: 'Find the Princess' }
  ];
})
```

It shows only the top navbar but no tasks in it but an interesting comment:

```
<ion-list><div class="list">
          <!-- ngRepeat: task in tasks -->
        </div></ion-list>
```

but if I pass an empty array as a second parameter of module then it just works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: No errors in the console when including `ionic`?

Comment: nope no error in the console whatsoever.

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `<ion-side-menu-content>` from the html and everything seems fine:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">Todo</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <!-- our list and list items -->
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        {{task.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

  </body>
```